# How to develop test cases for MEDIA_ROOT and STATIC_ROOT url patterns in Django?

Tags: django, django-tests

I have a Django web application, in which I am running test cases using coverage test tool.

I would like to know how to develop test cases for STATIC_ROOT and MEDIA_ROOT, since my coverage test states that for my urls.py file, the coverage is only 78%, the **following two url patterns have not been tested**.

[image: Coverage test]

I have researched a lot online, but couldn't find anything resourceful.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no point in writing test cases for these. Firstly, they are built-in Django functionality; and second they only work in development anyway, they are never used in production.

Trying to aim for 100% test coverage is a fool's errand. Coverage is a useful metric but it's more important to ensure real functionality is properly tested than to try and get to some imaginary goal of full coverage. After all, it's quite possible to have 100% coverage and for your code to still not be well tested at all, because you didn't write cases for all the different ways your code could be used.

Comment: Ok, will have it see how it pans out eventually